# User word2vec model output in larger kmeans project

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, word2vec, unsupervised-learning

I am attempting a rather large unsupervised learning project and am not sure how to properly utilize word2vec. We're trying to cluster groups of customers based on some stats about them and what actions they take on our website. Someone recommended I use word2vec and treat each action a user takes as a word in a "sentence". The reason this step is necessary is because a single customer can create multiple rows in the database (roughly same stats, but new row for each action on the website in chronological order). In order to perform kmeans on this data we need to get that down to one row per customer ID. Hence the previous idea to collapse down the actions as words in a sentence "describing the user's actions"

My question is I've come across countless tutorials and resources online that show you how to use word2vec (combined with kmeans) to cluster words on their own, but none of them show how to use the word2vec output as part of a larger kmeans model. I need to be able to use the word2vec model along side other values about the customer. How should I go about this? I'm using python for the clustering if you want to be specific with coding examples, but I could also just be missing something super obvious and high level. It seems the word2vec outputs vectors, but kmeans needs straight numbers to work, no? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How may total(maximum possible) actions are there??

Comment: There are around 36 different actions a user can take. But the column holds the list of _all_ actions the user takes. And since there is no min or max number of actions, those lists are of varying length.

Comment: Okay. Just trying to understand if there are 36 actions and say each action has a unique-id For eg action-1 has id = 1.

Then do the lists look like - [1,3,5,36], [2,5,6,2,6,7,4].
Two more questions-
Can the action be repeated for a user?? Is their any sequence to the actions??

Comment: Yes the actions are repeatable by each user. And while technically there is an order, functionally there is not. For instance a set of action might look like: [homepage, search, product list page, product page, product list page, product page, search, product page, checkout]

Comment: In your case problem with using word/sentence vectors with any clustering method or for that matter even supervised methods, is that all of the above methods need fixed vector length. You will have to cap the sequence length.

Comment: Comment was getting too long posting an answer @Marc

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches.

1. Taking the average of all words. That is easy, but the resulting vectors tend to be, well, average. They are not similar to the keywords of the document, but rather similar to the most average and least informative words... My experiences with this approach are pretty disappointing, despite this being the most mentioned approach.
2. par2vec/doc2vec. You add a "word" for each user to all it's contexts, in addition to the neighbor words, during training. This way you get a "predictive" vector for each paragraph/document/user the same way you get a word in the first word2vec. These are supposedly more informative but require much more effort to train - you can't download a pretrained model because they are computed during training.

Answer (score 0):

In your case problem with using word/sentence vectors with any clustering method or for that matter even supervised methods, is that all of the above methods need fixed vector length. You will have to cap the sequence length. You can use a lot of methods to convert these sequences into vectors.

Converting these sequences of word vectors to vectors is the challenge here.

You can average them out or concatenate them, but these things won't be very accurate plus the wont get better with time.
I found this really good paper...exactly what you want.[Try this](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W15-1509)

Benefit of building something like this or using an RNN is that later you could use the same model to try and predict the next most-likely action in addition to just clustering them.